# Weird result with bing numbers and percent cell

Tags: excel, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I'm working in a sheet with huge numbers, the sheet behaves as it should, but for one cell, same style/formatting inherited from the cells above. Here is what involved cell contains:

`**J13**: =(I13/E13)*100`

`**E13**: 588.000.000.000.000.000.000`

`**I13**: 4.340.000.000.000.000.000`

The cell `J13` **is formatted as a % value**, and I would expect a result of `0,74%` like other similar cels behave with similar big values, instead I'm getting a **73.81%** doing the math (4340 on 588000) I get the same result.
`

Answer (score 0):

You have missed some zeroes. Try dividing both values by `100000000000000000`. Then the results are `5880` and `43.4`. From there the result is ok. E.g., try the following and see the result:

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Debug.Print Round((43.4 / 5800) * 100, 4)    
End Sub
```

`74%` is really what should be given.

Comment: missed zeroes where? also trying with small numbers like 2940 and  6,51 I'm getting crazy values, in this case 22,14%

Comment: Try with `5880` and `43.4`. This is what you get if you divide both values by `100000000000000000`

Comment: so I essentially need to remove the `* 100` from my former formula and let the % formatting apply it?

Comment: _Vityata said: 74% is really what should be given_ Well no, I need to know what % the smaller numer is respect the bigger number, and in my case it should show 0,74% if the numbers were 100 and 10 it should show 10%

Comment: @Ritardi.Net - but you have times 100 after?